# Stroking gradient on a uibezier circular path in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gradient, alpha, uibezierpath

i want to draw a circular/ arc path with gradient. Gradient is of single color, at start angle color has alpha value zero and for end angle alpha value of color is equal to radian of point mapped between 0-1.

Comment: can you add an example Image to your question?